# Selecting every first option of multiple select elements

Tags: jquery

I have an html file with multiple select elements. What is needed is that the text of every first option of a select element is changed with jQuery. The answer given is `$('select').children().first().html('changed!');`. But this does not change *all* the first option texts, only the first one.

What is the proper way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.each()`:

```
$('select').each(function() {
    $(this).children().first().text('changed!');
});
```

Note that you should use `text()`, not `html()` in this case, as the content of `<option>` elements is supposed to be plain text.

Alternatively, you can select the first option elements directly, avoiding the use of `children()` and `first()`:

```
$('select>option:first-child').each(function() {
    $(this).text('changed!');
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why the author of this book chose .html to accomplish this. It is not the best of books! The solution works, but was not mentioned up till now in the book. Anyways, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may also use [nth-child-selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) to select the first, the second ....

In order to change the text of all selected elements you may use:

```
$('select option:nth-child(1)').text('changed');
```

or:

```
$('select option:nth-child(1)').text(function(index, text) {
    return 'changed';
});
```

This because jQuery offers the [text-function](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function).

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  //$('select option:nth-child(1)').text('changed');

  // or
  $('select option:nth-child(1)').text(function(index, text) {
    return 'changed';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wow, that's quite an answer! Thank you! This one works great as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options in Jquery iterate on descants. You have used children()  which not iterate recursively means only direct children are considered.The other is find() which iterate recursively means all grandchildrens are considered along with direct childrens. I think if you change your code as following :

```
$('select').find("option").first().html('changed!');
```

Please do not hesistate to ask . Hope Helps !!!

You need to iterate on all selects :

```
$("select").each(function(index,item){
         $(item).find("option").first().html('changed!');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Osman. Unfortunately, it did not work out; it only changed the first option of the first select, not the others.